# Vuetify 3 with vue 3, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I'm new to FE developing and vueJS, but I'm upgrading an Vue 2 application to Vue 3Using Vue v 3.2.13 and Vuetify v 3.1.15 currently.

Problem is the some components just don't seem to exist.

For example  exists according to documentation (no?), but I still get the error:"Filed to resolve component: v-data-table"

What am I doing wrong, or is anybody even using Vuetify with Vue 3 successfully?

I'm using Veutify mainly because it was used when the application was on Vue 2, and thought it would be easy to migrate and keep the same FW. Are there better alternatives and I should change the FW?

Answer (score 1):

VDataTable for Vuetify 3 is still in development, you have to add the current experimental version (Vuetify calls it "labs") manually by registering it in `createVuetify()`:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components: {
        VDataTable,
    },
})
```

Check the [documentation for labs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/)